# While handling the quiz app in react,wrapping options by using array doesn't working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please tell me where i am going wrong? This line gives a error:

```
const options = Array.form(document.querySelectorAll('.option'));
console.log(options);
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be Array.from() instead of Array.form()?

Answer (score 0):

Its Array.from(), what you are trying is Array.form()